# Metodo para Insertar y Eliminar desde spring-boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

Hola buenas estoy dando mis primeros pasos con SpringBoot, y estoy intentando crear un servicio que primero elimine todos los valores de una tabla que estén ligados a un id y después inserte nuevos valores como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tengo el siguiente código para lo anterior:

**Model:**

```html
@Entity
@Table(name="roles_modulos")
@IdClass(RolesModulosId.class)
public class RolesModulos implements Serializable{
    
    @Id
    private Long role_id;
    @Id
    private Long modulo_id;
    
    public Long getRole_id() {
        return role_id;
    }
    public void setRole_id(Long role_id) {
        this.role_id = role_id;
    }
    public Long getModulo_id() {
        return modulo_id;
    }
    public void setModulo_id(Long modulo_id) {
        this.modulo_id = modulo_id;
    }
    
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

**Repo**

```js
public interface RolesModulosDao extends CrudRepository<RolesModulos, Long>{

    @Query(value="delete from roles_pantallas where role_id = :role_id", nativeQuery =true)
     void deleteRolesModulosz(@Param("role_id") Long role_id);
    
}
```

**Service Imp**

```js
import com.ocb.reporteria.model.sql.RolesModulos;
import com.ocb.reporteria.repo.sql.RolesModulosDao;

public class RolModuloSeviceIMP implements RolModuloService {

    @Autowired
    private RolesModulosDao rolmodulosDao;
    
    @Override
    public List<RolesModulos> saveRolesModulosz(List<RolesModulos> rolesmodulosList) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return (List<RolesModulos>) rolmodulosDao.saveAll(rolesmodulosList);
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteRolesModulosz(Long id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         rolmodulosDao.deleteById(id);
    }

}
```

**Service**

```js
import com.ocb.reporteria.model.sql.RolesModulos;

public interface RolModuloService {

       public List<RolesModulos> saveRolesModulosz(List<RolesModulos> rolesmodulosListz);
       
       public void deleteRolesModulosz(Long id);
    
}
```

**Controller**

```js
@PostMapping("/roles-modulos/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<?> deleteRolesModulosz(@PathVariable Long id, @RequestBody List<RolesModulos> rolmodulo ){
        Map<String, Object> response = new HashMap<>();
        rolmoduloSer.deleteRolesModulosz(id);
        rolmoduloSer.saveRolesModulosz(rolmodulo);
        //System.out.print(rolesmodulos);
        response.put("mensaje", "Modulos Asignados con exito!");
        return new ResponseEntity<Map<String,Object>>(response,HttpStatus.OK);
        
    }
```

Cuando intento ejecutarlo en Postman me salta el siguente mensaje:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No entiendo porque me salta este mensaje, no se si el request que mando en la petición desde postman esta mal estructurado o el servicio que estoy haciendo esta mal.

Comment: Para cambiar el tipo de contenido donde Postman muestra `Text` has clic y selecciona `JSON ` para que Postman envié en el encabezado con el tipo de contenido correcto.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La respuesta tiene el estado `HTTP 415 Unsuported Media Type`.
Estás intentando mandar una request con un JSON, pero la cabecera (el *header*) Content-Type indica `text/plain`.
Eso hace que Spring no sepa cómo procesar la petición, ya que entiende que no es ni un XML ni un JSON, que son los formatos que su "mapeador" Jackson procesa por defecto.

Asegúrate de añadir el valor correcto: `Content-type: application/json`